# Adding a custom button to WordPress Add Post (and Edit Post too) screen, that can save the post

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a plugin that hides the publish box from authors, so that I can have them click on a button in a custom meta box I created, to save their post. (This is not the sole purpose of the plugin, rest, I can't share. But this step is needed to do the rest.)

I want WordPress to save the post to DB as it normally would, when I click on that button.

How do I invoke WordPress' post save action from a custom button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution couldn't be more obvious.

The Add New Post screen is a one big form. Any `<input type="submit"/>` element you put in it will save the post.